# Malformed search query

Tags: search, search-scope, enterprise-search, fulltextsqlquery

I'm trying to perform search on a single list using `FullTextSqlQuery`.
I found example here, but given this query:

```
"SELECT Title,ContentType,Path FROM portal..scope() WHERE freetext('" + query + "') AND (CONTAINS(Path,'\"" + list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "\"'))"
```

which for example could look like this:

```
SELECT Title,ContentType,Path FROM portal..scope() WHERE freetext('samochód') AND (CONTAINS(Path,'"/BW/Lists/Pytania Bazy Wiedzy"'))
```

but I'm getting unhandled exception on query execution:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.QueryMalformedException: Your query is malformed. Please rephrase your query.
```

This is my first contact with performing search programatically so I have no idea what might be wrong with this query. Any information and help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `portal..` part isn't correct and try specifying a column for the `freetext` predicate like this:

```
SELECT Title,ContentType,Path FROM SCOPE() WHERE FREETEXT(DefaultProperties,'samochód') AND (CONTAINS(Path,'"/BW/Lists/Pytania Bazy Wiedzy"'))
```